# How to get the type information of a record by its pointer in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, pointers, delphi-xe, record, rtti

If I have a TList with many pointers of different record types in it, how do I access the values of the differents records within the TList?

Is there any way to get the record type or type information of those referenced recods?

I'm currently using Delphi XE.

Comment: I don't know anything about RTTI but I don't think pointers to records carry type information with them. Am I wrong?

Comment: try this PRecord(List[i])^.member where PRecord is ^Yourdefinedrecord ... I don't really understand the question...

Comment: @opc0de I think the question is about lists where you don't know what type is in the list. Otherwise it is as trivial as your comment.

Comment: Good point didn't understand the question thanks for clearing things up for me.

Answer (score 6):

Your different record types need a common header.  You can then cast the list item pointers to that header type first to determine what record type to cast to next.  For example:

```
type
  TRecType = (recA, recB, recC);

  PRecHeader = ^TRecHeader;
  TRecHeader = record
    RecType: TRecType;
    ...
  end;

  PRecordA = ^TRecordA;
  TRecordA = record
    Header: TRecHeader;
    IntValue: Integer;
  end;

  PRecordB = ^TRecordB;
  TRecordB = record
    Header: TRecHeader;
    StrValue: String;
  end;

  PRecordC = ^TRecordC;
  TRecordC = record
    Header: TRecHeader;
    DblValue: Double;
  end;

var
  PRec: Pointer;
begin
  PRec := List[Index];
  case PRecHeader(PRec)^.RecType of
    recA: use PRecordA(PRec)^.IntValue as needed ...
    recB: use PRecordB(PRec)^.StrValue as needed ...
    recC: use PRecordC(PRec)^.DblValue as needed ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Would be much easier just to use a variant record rather than reimplement it.

Comment: Even a variant record needs a header value that is outside of the variant area to know which portion of the variant data to access.

Comment: Yes, but the syntax is much cleaner. Of course if you are using managed types, like a string, then you can't use variant records!

Comment: Primordial polymorphism. The compiler tree of FPC 1.0.x was that way.

Answer (score 3):

You really can't do it this way.  Unlike Delphi objects, records don't carry any RTTI around with them.  If you're mixing a bunch of pieces of data of different types and you want to be able to find out what type of data they are at runtime, the best thing to do is simply use objects, which inherit `TObject.ClassType` and a handful of other routines to make this task simple.

If you really need to use records for whatever reason, you'll have to begin each record with a custom tag that doesn't change.  I was about to describe the system, but it looks like Remy beat me to it. But this comes with enough overhead that, again, you may as well just use objects instead, as once you go very far down this road you're basically reimplementing a lot of of `TObject` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise to use the `TObjectList` object from the `Contnrs` unit. (Is it still there in Delphi XE?) This is based on `TList`, but does the work for you to offer `TObject` references instead of pointers. It's a subtle difference, but allows you direct use of the `is` and `as` operators on the list's items.

Comment: `TObjectList` is still there in XE, but is not really helpful with record pointers.

Comment: @TOndrej I believe the suggestion is to move away from records which do not carry around type information.

Answer (score 1):

How about using object pascal style with {$M+}?. This will eliminate the overhead of TObject

```
{$M+}

TRecordA = object
end;

TRecordB = object
end;

{$M-}
```

Comment: There could be a good answer in here, but it needs some elaboration